# Overriding core model not working

Tags: magento-1.8, catalog, model, core

I want to override **Mage_Catalog_Model_Config**.

**app/code/local/Myname/Catalog/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>    
    <modules>
        <Myname_Catalog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Myname_Catalog>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <config>Myname_Catalog_Model_Config</config>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/etc/modules/Myname_Catalog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Myname_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Myname_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Why on Earth is this not working??

Answer (score 5):

You did not **define your own model**:

Your `app/code/local/Myname/Catalog/etc/config.xml` should look like this (note the `<myname_catalog>` section):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>    
    <modules>
        <Myname_Catalog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Myname_Catalog>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <myname_catalog>
                <class>Myname_Catalog_Model</class>
            </myname_catalog>

            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <config>Myname_Catalog_Model_Config</config>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your app/etc/modules/Myname_Catalog.xml file like below

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Myname_Catalog>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    <depends>
            <Mage_Catalog />
        </depends>
    </Myname_Catalog>
</modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your below code

```
<global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <config>Myname_Catalog_Model_Config</config>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
```

to

```
<global>
    <models>
        <catalog>
        <class>Myname_Catalog_Model</class>
    </catalog>
        <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <config>Myname_Catalog_Model_Config</config>
        </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </models>
</global>
```

If it don't work after changing above code, trying changing your modulename i.e. "catalog" to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Update Module tag of your `Myname_Catalog.xml` inside `app/etc/modules`:

```
            <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core/>
                <Mage_Eav/>
            </depends>
```

If it is an Eav Model you creating, else you will need to make it `<depend/>`
 on `<(AnotherNameSpace_ModuleName) />`

```
<depends>
```

directives only establish a load order (or error) for module `config.xml` files